# Workaround to hide browser headers when printing from browsers?

Tags: printing

I need to allow printing from my web app that hides default browser headers (eg. the URL and "Page x of y"). I specifically need a workaround that does not require a) browser settings modifications by the user or b) first outputting to a PDF. Neither of these extra steps are acceptable for my situation.

As you can see in the screenshot below, it says "print test - Google Docs" along with the URL. These are the headers. I do not want these to show up.

[image]

Is there a way I can a) hide headers via Javascript, b) print via an embedded Flash SWF or Java Applet, or c) something else?

Comment: Some more info are needed. Is it a popup ? How do you hide the "browser headers" ?

Comment: I have added information to the question. Please see that.

Answer (score -4):

Without any more info, I can just suggest this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()"> 
<img src="print_image.gif" BORDER="0"</a>
```

Take a look here http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471121/Print-a-Web-Page-Using-JavaScript.htm, if it doesn't fit your needs, please give us more details.

Comment: As you can see here -- http://chadjohnson.ath.cx/static/screenshots/e2dc0b2c706afe348573238436d90b0c.png -- it says "print test - Google Docs" along with the URL. I do not want this to show up. How can I make this not show?

Comment: -1 doesn't remove the header and the footer. It's basically a fancy ctrl+p